# Composition with lambda expressions haskell

Tags: haskell, lambda, composition

I try a dummy example of using composition with lambda expression. The below code compile, but it doesn't run when I try `(f.g) 3 2`

```
f x = x^2
g x = 5*x

f.g = \x -> f(g x)
```

It gives such an error:

```
Ambiguous occurrence `.'
It could refer to
   either `Prelude..',
          imported from `Prelude' at list3.hs:1:1
          (and originally defined in `GHC.Base')
       or `Main..', defined at list3.hs:42:3.
```

Can somebody please tell me where is the problem?

Comment: There is already a definition for `(.)`, so you defined a function with the same name.

Comment: it's worth noting that even when you resolve this (eg by removing your definition of `.`, which is equivalent to that in Prelude), `(f . g) 3 2` will still fail to compile because `f . g` takes a single number and produces a number, so `(f . g) 3` is a simple number and can't therefore be applied to the number 2.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You defined a composition operator that exists *along side* the one imported from the Prelude. There's nothing wrong with the *definition*; the problem occurs when you try to *use* it, as the compiler can't tell if something like

```
main = print $ f . g $ 10
```

is supposed to use `.` from the Prelude or `.` from your `Main` module.

One solution is to simply be explicit about which of the two you want.

```
f . g = \x -> f (g x)

main = print $ f Main.. g $ 10
```

or to not import the Prelude version in the first place.

```
{-# LANGUAGE NoImplicitPrelude #-}

import Prelude hiding ((.))

-- Now this is the *only* definition.
f . g = \x -> f (g x)

main = print $ f . g $ 10
```

Answer (score 0):

As explained in the excellent answer by chepner, your '.' dot operator is in conflict with the regular '.' operator implicitly imported from the Haskell Prelude. This is what the error message means.

Fortunately, the [Unicode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode) character set is supported by the Haskell compiler, and it happens to offer the proper function composition character as seen in math books, that is '∘', in decimal position 8728.

And this '∘' operator is **NOT** (as yet) defined by the Prelude.

Hence, the following code works fine:

```
main :: IO ()
main = do
    let
         -- our own function composition operator:
         fna ∘ fnb  =  \x -> fna (fnb x)  -- Unicode character #8728 (decimal)

         f x    =   x * x
         g x    =   5 * x
         h      =   f ∘ g  -- composed function

         res    =   h 7
    putStrLn $ "res = " ++ (show res)
```

and it prints a result of 1225, as you would expect.